# How to be aware of missing values during multi-value iteration in Perl 6?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, raku, rakudo

During multi-value iteration, if we run out of values, the last group of values will not be handled in the current version of Rakudo.

```
my @arr = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
for @arr -> $a, $b, $c, $d {
  say $a
  say $b
  say $c
  say $d
}
```

The result is

```
1
2
3
4
```

, which drops `5` and `6`.

So in which way I am able get the elements that are dropped?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@choroba's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44225309/1160124) notes, your code actually throws an error in Perl 6.c.

The error occurs on the second iteration, when only `5, 6` is left from the input array, which can't be mapped to the signature `$a, $b, $c, $d` because all four parameters in that signature are mandatory.

There are multiple ways to make it work:

#### A) Mark the parameters as optional.

```perl6
for @arr -> $a, $b?, $c?, $d? {
    say "---";
    say $a;
    say $b if $b.defined;
    say $c if $c.defined;
    say $d if $d.defined;
}
```

The `?` means optional – i.e. when no argument is passed to that parameter, it's set to the value `Mu` ("most undefined"). Note that there's no need to mark the *first* parameter as optional, because when there are zero input elements left the `for` loop terminates and doesn't try to enter another iteration.
Output:

```
---
1
2
3
4
---
5
6
```

#### B) Specify defaults for the parameters.

```perl6
for @arr -> $a, $b = 'default-B', $c = 'default-C', $d = 'default-D' {
    say ($a, $b, $c, $d);
}
```

This is what @choroba already suggested. It's essentially another way of making the parameters optional, but now with a custom value instead of `Mu` in case no argument was passed to them.
Output:

```
(1 2 3 4)
(5 6 default-C default-D)
```

#### C) Use `.rotor` to handle the partitioning.

Using a `for` block with a multi-parameter signature is not the only way to iterate a list of values n-at-a-time. The `.rotor` method provides the same functionality in a more functional style. It skips partial iterations at the end by default, so you need to give it the `:partial` option to include that iteration:

```perl6
for @arr.rotor(4, :partial) -> @slice {
    say @slice;
}
```

For each iteration, `@slice` becomes a List of 4 elements, except for the last iteration where it can have fewer elements.. (You could check `@slice.elems` inside the loop body to see how many you got.)
Output:

```
(1 2 3 4)
(5 6)
```

Answer (score 5):

Trying in Rakudo Star I've just installed:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /home/choroba/1.p6
Unexpected block in infix position (missing statement control word before the expression?)
at /home/choroba/1.p6:2
------> for @arr⏏ -> $a, $b, $c, $d {
    expecting any of:
        infix
        infix stopper
```

After adding semicolons everywhere, I'm getting

```
1
2
3
4
Too few positionals passed; expected 4 arguments but got 2
  in block <unit> at /home/choroba/1.p6 line 2
```

You can provide default values if you don't want to get an error:

```
for @arr -> $a,
            $b = 'Missing b',
            $c = 'Missing c',
            $d = 'Missing d' {
```

As [smls](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1160124/smls) comments, you can also make the variables optional:

```
for @arr -> $a, $b?, $c?, $d? {
```

which will work the same as using `$var = Mu`.